# <select> items not loading using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, materialize

My issue might looks very super simple but I am struggling how to load items into a select using Jquery. I am using Materialize theme found here: https://pixinvent.com/materialize-material-design-admin-template/html/ltr/vertical-modern-menu-template/

I have this. Simple:

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="selectid">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>

  @section Scripts{
     <script src="~/app-assets/js/vendors.min.js"></script>
     <script src="~/app-assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
     <script src="~/app-assets/js/search.js"></script>
     <script src="~/app-assets/js/custom/custom-script.js"></script>
      <script>

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#selectid').append(`<option value="${"10"}">${"test1"}</option>`);
            $('#selectid').append(`<option value="${"11"}">${"test2"}</option>`);
            $('#selectid').append(`<option value="${"12"}">${"test3"}</option>`);
        });

      </script>
  }
```

my problem is that my appended items are not working:

[image]

BUT if I move the append code outside of `$( document ).ready()` it works. But I am trying to load them inside it while page loads.

Why is this not working? How do I solve this?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me using this in plain html: https://pastecode.io/s/zqg3wkyi

Are there any console errors? Also, I don't see the reference to jquery in there, is it in the layout file and confirmed to be loading fine?

Answer (score 0):

there are many reason for this. But the most common is conflicts between your code and other js or jquery codes - so just run your code in **no conflict mode** by simply adding this line **above your document.ready() function** block.

```
$.noConflict();
```

and then replace all jQuery shortcut **$** in you code by **jQuery**.

Or for shorter version:

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
```

and replace all jQuery shortcut **$** in you code by **jq**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo with [official sample](https://materializecss.com/select.html) of Materialize.You can put the append code before initialize code.

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="selectid">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#selectid').append(`<option value="${"10"}">${"test1"}</option>`);
            $('#selectid').append(`<option value="${"11"}">${"test2"}</option>`);
            $('#selectid').append(`<option value="${"12"}">${"test3"}</option>`);
            $('#selectid').formSelect();
        });
       
    </script>
}
```

result:
[image]